# How do I remove "\\r" characters from text in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following job description text:

```
Why settle for an ordinary sales career, when you can put more life in your career with us? Colonial Life has an immediate opening for SALES REPRESENTATIVES to join our growing team.\\r\\rWe are a leader in worksite marketing. We work with employers and their employees to provide benefit solutions in one neat package: benefits communication, enrollment, and personal insurance products.\\r\\rSkills/backgrounds associated with success are:\\r\\r    Experience attaining challenging sales goals.\\r    Ability to identify and prioritize sales opportunities.\\r    Effective verbal and written communication skills, and\xa0ability to successfully engage all levels of customer base.\\r    Self-motivation and drive; willing to invest time in developing client relationships. \\r\\r\\rCareer Opportunities:\\r\\r\\r    Prospect, market and deliver benefit communications and enrollment solutions to decision makers.\\r    Present voluntary product solutions to employees. \\r\\r\\r\\rWe provide the tools, training and support to help you succeed. With Colonial Life, you can:\\r\xa0 \\r\\r    Achieve more than just sales – enjoy being a benefits counselor.\\r    Work with a sound company that’s had a solid history of integrity and growth for more than 70 years.\\r    Enjoy strong earnings potential, even in your first year, plus competitive bonuses and incentives. Average first-year income for our top new benefit counselors hit $105,000 last year. \\r    Grow and refine your skills through our proven phone prospecting system and structured sales training program.\\r    Enjoy a flexible work schedule.\\r    Earn what you’re worth, help people, and have fun doing it! \\r\\r'
```

I'm trying to:
a) get rid of all the "\r", "\r\r" or "\r\r\r" characters in the main text
b) print it in sentences so it's more readable

How do I do both a) and b)?

I have tried `re.sub(r'[^ \w\.]', '', sentence)` for a) and it removed the "\" but not the "r" so I ended up with something like that:

```
'Why settle for an ordinary sales career when you can put more life in your career with us Colonial Life has an immediate opening for SALES REPRESENTATIVES to join our growing team.rrWe are a leader in worksite marketing. We work with employers and their employees to provide benefit solutions in one neat package benefits communication enrollment and personal insurance products.rrSkillsbackgrounds associated with success arerr    ...
```

Comment: how about sentence.replace('\\r','') ?

Comment: Try this: `re.sub(r"(?:\\+r)+|[^ \w.]+", "", sentence)`

Comment: The `\\r` which appear in your string look very suspicious, because it seems they should really just be `\r` carriage returns.  What is the source of this string/text?

Comment: Why would you use regex to remove a fixed character? Would you use regex to remove all `a`'s? Removing all `\r`'s is no different. Regex is not needed for this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using a Kaggle dataset for Job Descriptions and some of the data descriptions include HTML tags. Here's the link for the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/bman93/dataset

Comment: @anubhava your suggestion has improved it greatly but it still has some characters left. e.g. 'Why settle for an ordinary sales career when you can put more life in your career with us Colonial Life has an immediate opening for SALES REPRESENTATIVES to join our growing team.We are a leader in worksite marketing. We work with employers and their employees to provide benefit solutions in one neat package benefits communication enrollment and personal insurance products.Skillsbackgrounds associated with success arer  Experience attaining challenging sales goals. " : Notice the "r" in "arer"?

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer it's worked yes, thank you!

Comment: @Angelo: please try this as regex: `r"(?:\\+r)+|[^ \w.\\]+"`

Comment: @Tomalak I see your point. I'm novice in text manipulation so assumed that regex would solve my problem. A simple replace did the job. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava this has improved it so much better and also removed other unwanted characters like "\xa0". But in this case has left words sections like:

  
Before: 
```Effective verbal and written communication skills, and\xa0ability to successfully engage all levels of customer base.```


After: 
```Effective verbal and written communication skills, andability to successfully engage all levels of customer base.```

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: So you expect `and\xa0ability` to become `and ability` ?

Comment: @anubhava yes exactly.

Comment: See if this works for you: https://regex101.com/r/M2daiW/1

Comment: @Zhubai Federer do you want to add your comment as an answer so I can accept this question?